# How to change a column type of a BigQuery table by querying and exporting to itself?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a `integer` type column in my BigQuery table and now I need to convert it to a `float` column. I also have to keep all records. What I want to do is ***changing the column type***. Not casting.

I've read that it's possible to do it just by exporting results of a query on a table to itself.

How to do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Using SELECT with writing result back to table

```
SELECT 
  CAST(int_field AS FLOAT) AS float_field, 
  <all_other_fields> 
FROM YourTable
```

This approach will co$t you scan of whole table

To execute this  - you should use **Show Option** button in **BQ Web UI** and properly set options as in below example. After you run this  - your table will have that column with float vs. original integer data type as you wanted. Note: You should use proper/same field name for both int_field and float_field

[image]

if you would just needed to add new column I would point you to [Tables: patch GBQ API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/patch).
I am not sure if this API allows to change type of column - I doubt  - but it is easy to check

> Using [Jobs: insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) EXTRACT and then LOAD

Here you can extract table to GCS and then load it back to GBQ with adjusted schema

Above approach will a) eliminate cost cost of querying (scan) tables and b) can help with limitations that you can come up if you have complex schame (with records/repeated/nested, etc. type /mode)

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for answer. However I want to change the schema and I'd like to know how it is done only using queries. Just like mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703701/bigquery-how-can-i-change-the-type-of-one-of-my-column-from-integer-to-string

Comment: see "Using SELECT ..." section in my answer. what is else that you need to know? if this is not enough - you might want to provide more details in your question

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough. I'm not interested in 'casting' within a query. I want to change data type of the column.

Comment: I add some more into answer - hope this help to see that this is most likely exactly what is your question. you might still have something different in mind. but at least i tried :o)

Comment: And don't forget about <all_other_fileds>!

Comment: One potential issue with that is for partitioned tables if you need to rely on the `_PARTITIONTIME` field for your daily tasks

Comment: I need the same use case, but I have `_PARTITIONTIME` (My table is partitioned one), so how to copy to the destination table with field `_PARTITIONTIME`?