# How to change a column type from TIMESTAMP to DATE of a BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a TIMESTAMP type column that I wish to change to a DATE type in an already existing bigquery table. I have tried this solution [How to change a column type of a BigQuery table by querying and exporting to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071216/how-to-change-a-column-type-of-a-bigquery-table-by-querying-and-exporting-to-its) but I would like to keep all existing fields instead of overwriting the whole table.

Here is what I have tried
`SELECT CAST (DATE(csysdate) AS DATE) AS csdate from [TABLE]`

Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: The other question you've linked to is exactly what you need. The solution by Mikhail preserves all the exisiting columns too i.e. _"<all_other_fields> "_

Comment: Sorry I was a bit confused there. So I should write all existing fields that are in that table? Because at the moment they are about a hundred columns making it quite difficult.

Comment: Just use `*` for all other columns!

Comment: Terrific stuff!