# How to cast data type when loading MongoDB json file into Google big query?

Tags: json, mongodb, casting, google-bigquery

The problem I have with load data using `bq` is that I have string and integer values for a field called `cost` for instance. That its value is 0 or a string value "1.0" and so one. So data type differs per record.

What I currently use to load data is:

```
bq load --autodetect --ignore_unknown_values=true --max_bad_records=100 --project_id=my-proj-100605 --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON my_dataset.my_table ./mongo_export.json
```

And it gives the error below:

```
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'my-proj-100605:bqjob_r2cfcfa271ed999bb_0059a0fba75_1': Invalid
schema update. Field to has changed type from INTEGER to STRING
```

Any solution when loading data from a json file to cast the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specifically cast a type when uploading data. You must do a casting after or before loading data. Some castings are be done automatically as you will see in my example. You could kind of specify a casting if you understand how it'd be done automatically. Continue reading for a better understanding:

I have done a test using the UI and the CLI with:

> ```
> {"col1": "b", "col2": 0}
> {"col1": "c", "col2": 0}
> {"col1": "d", "col2": "1.0"}
> {"col1": "e", "col2": "1.0"}
> {"col1": "f", "col2": "1.0"}
> {"col1": "g", "col2": 0}
> {"col1": "h", "col2": 0}
> {"col1": "i", "col2": 0}
> ```

And the first column has been imported as string and the second as float. I used the exactly same command:

```
bq load --autodetect --ignore_unknown_values=true --max_bad_records=100 --project_id=MYPROJECTid --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON dataset.tablename ./jsontoimp.json
```

So I couldn't reproduce your issue, to me it's ok. Anyway, you have two options if it's not being recognized as it should:

1.- Just specify the schema with this column as string or code some script to replace 0 by "0". Then load this data. Once all it's uploaded you can update the type of the column. [Long explanation here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#changing_a_columns_data_type). This doesn't look the cheapest solution.

2.- What I would do, code some script, maybe with a regex, to replace "1.0" to 1.0 and then, after this, upload the procesed file.

More information about [updating data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data) and [castings in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting).

Comment: More info about changing column type: [How to change a column type of a BigQuery table by querying and exporting to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071216/how-to-change-a-column-type-of-a-bigquery-table-by-querying-and-exporting-to-its)