# Changing the data type in BigQuery for a partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have a partitioned table in BigQuery to store user events, which has following schema,

```
user_id - String, Required
event_time - DateTime, Required
country - String, Nullable
_PARTITIONTIME - event occurred date
```

Above table holds two years worth of data (means 730 partitions).

For some reason I would like to change the data type from `DateTime` to `Timestamp`. I found a similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374004/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-data-type-in-google-bigquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703701/bigquery-how-can-i-change-the-type-of-one-of-my-column-from-integer-to-string), those are working fine for non-partitioned table. But in my case, I have partitioned table so I need to retain the value `_PARTITIONTIME` as such.

After some research I found, running the following query with `Destination Table` as `table_name$20180126` seems to achieve my goal for a single partition,

```
SELECT user_id, CAST(event_time AS TIMESTAMP) AS event_time, country from [project-id:data_set.table_name] WHERE _PARTITIONTIME >= "2018-01-26 00:00:00" AND _PARTITIONTIME < "2018-01-27 00:00:00"
```

But the problem is, I have 730 partition for a table (similarly I have 10 more table like this), running above query one by one in web console or through API or through BQ command line will take ages. Is there is any other better way to achieve the use case with minimal work effort?

Comment: Although DDL has been recently launched it only support Create and Delete syntax. No update yet. Scripting this as you mentioned, is the way to go. It should not take forever as you can issue multiple one in parallel.

Comment: @Pentium10 - if scripted, does that mean 730 full table scans ($$$) ?

Comment: @GrahamPolley Do you suggest any other approach?

Comment: I'm thinking you could use Dataflow or Mikhails approach over here (slightly tweaked of course): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993877/migrating-from-non-partitioned-to-partitioned-tables

Comment: @JayaAnanthram you say it's already partitioned, so 730 queries each reading their respective partition, results in 1 full table scan.

Comment: @Pentium10, Yes my table is partitioned one, so I will be charged for one full table scan (Since each query is bounded with corresponding partition). But my main concern is, in production some downstream application will be using bigquery, so I want to minimize the schema update timings and downtime for a table. (Something like, `doing for each partition doing it for complete table`, AFAIK each partition will reside in separate file so I am trying to do across files in a single command) .

Comment: Could you patch your table with a  new column. Run an update statement to populate the new column. Eventually rewrite the table by removing the old column(either keep it).  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch

Comment: This is a good idea @Pentium10.

Comment: @Pentium10 I think I didn't get you. For DML updates, daily limit is 10,000, So I need to increase that (Fine for now). What do you mean by rewrite the table? Rewrite to a new table? If yes, then there is no point of doing UPDATE right? Simply I can cast the field while rewriting to a new table right? (Though I need to do it for each partition).. Am I correct or am i missing anything?

Comment: Sorry I need to correct something. DML for partitioned tables are not yet supported. I did remembered wrong. You need to rewrite the table with scripting. You can test that on a copy of your dataset. The 10k limit btw is the number  of queries. And a DML query can update the whole table. It's not number of rows.

Comment: @Pentium10 I thought update should be ran for every partition, that's the reason i was wondering about quota. So finally, I am going to rewrite the table with scripting for every partition (quite hectic stuff). Just wondering whether it is worth to raise enhancement `Write to new destination table with partition column`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram this has been released today, you might be interested: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a lot of discussion in the comments, but I want to highlight two things.

1. As of today you can [create partitioned tables using an existing column](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions) TIMESTAMP or DATETIME type as the partition definer.
2. Also there is a guide pubished for [Manually Changing Table Schemas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas)

You may want to read both recommendations especially the first one come handy to you, and you would choose reloading data for lots of benefits.

Comment: Thanks for the update, really interesting. I hope it will help me. But I am afraid of beta warning in the documentation `This is a beta release of column-based, time-partitioned tables. This feature might be changed in backward-incompatible ways and is not subject to any SLA or deprecation policy.` (Since I want to do in my PROD environment).. Anyways I will have a look on it..

Comment: Don't be afraid. Google has tens of projects still in beta.